# Synchronize multiple web-servers when using Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql, synchronization, load-balancing

Today I'm running a single asp.net 4 iis web-server and a single SQL-server. But now i need to start a second web-server to manage the load i get. The problem is when i use Linq the framework caches data from the database on the web-server resulting in the server getting out of sync. i always run (sample) DatabaseDataContext.MyTable.First(some condition) and i always submit the data to the database after changing it, but I still get old data that is cached on the web-server that did not do the change.

How do i solve this, is there any settings like forcing Linq to check last modified or any other checks on the tables involved.

Any ideas or tutorials on how to manage multiple servers and using Linq.

BR
Andreas

Comment: Do you dispose you DataContext after each request?

Comment: No i don't. Will this not generate a big performance problem to empty the entire context every time?